# Beheading of knights, who survives?

Tags: python, python-3.x

> We have a round table of `n` knights, where `n` is some positive
>   integer. These have failed to satisfy the expectations of the mad king
>   and are sentenced to death. However as an act of mercy he goes around
>   the table killing every *other* knight (starting with the second)
>   until only *one* knight remains.
>
> The question is: *which seat do you need to pick to survive?*

I wrote the primitive code below to tackle this problem:

```
while True:
    temp_num = input("Enter the number of knights: ")
    try:
        temp_num = int(temp_num)
        if temp_num <= 0:  # if not a positive int print message and ask for input again
            print("Sorry, the number of knights must be a positive integer, try again")
        else:
            knights_num = temp_num
            break
    except ValueError:
        print("That's not an integer!")     
# else all is good, val is >=  0 and an integer

# Create a table of knights and a temp table
knights_table = [i for i in range(1,knights_num+1)]
knights_temp_table = list(knights_table)

i = 1
while len(knights_temp_table)>1:
# print("Knights =",knights_temp_table , "(",knights_temp_table[i],")")
    knights_temp_table.pop(i)
    i = (i+1)%len(knights_temp_table)
print( "The knight who survived was no.",knights_temp_table[0] )
```

The code runs fine and outputs the expected values `n=60> 57` and `n=16 > 1`
However from the code it is not clear *why* it works. So i had some questions below

- Could the table of knights be made using a generator?
- Is a code using `try` `knights_temp_table[i+1]` and `knights_temp_table[i+2]` and then iterating over the list for the exceptions clearer?
- Could one implement a linked list to make the code clearer instead of modulo?

I know the code is very simple and the problem I solved almost trivial. However any suggestions is much appreaciated since I am a semi-begginer / novice at python.
 * Are there any other general suggestions to improve the code, or running speed?

Comment: Based on your code I presume you're using Python 2.7. But can you confirm it? Your code runs differently in different versions.

Comment: You might also be interested in these Java reviews : http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/56951/100-gunmen-in-circle-kill-next-person / http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/86023/100-gunmen-in-a-circle-kill-next-person

Comment: Oh I am running 3.4 what are those differences? I thought it was mainly the use of parenthesis.

Comment: @N3buchadnezzar In Python3 range will return a generator function instead of a list directly, which is presumably why you called `list()`. In Python 2.x, `range` just returns a list directly, making that step skippable. Apart from that the only difference for you is the `print` function needing parentheses in 3, whereas in 2 you *could* leave them out (but it's not advised).

Comment: FYI This is the centuries-old [Josephus Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Josephus_problem)

Answer (score 29, accepted):

**Use a function**

You can move your entire input loop into a function. Call it something reasonable:

```
def get_num_knights():
    while True:
        num = input("Enter the number of knights: ")
        try:
            num = int(num)
            if num <= 0:  # if not a positive int print message and ask for input again
                print("Sorry, the number of knights must be a positive integer, try again")
            else:
                return num
        except ValueError:
            print("That's not an integer!")
```

That's good for two reasons: modularity is always nice, and now you don't have to worry about name collisions. Just use `num` internally, and `return` when you're done.

**Two lists**

This:

```
knights_table = [i for i in range(1,knights_num+1)]
knights_temp_table = list(knights_table)
```

makes two `list`s. The first is a list-comprehension that produces a `list`, the second just copies it. There's no reason for the duplication. Furthermore,

```
range(1, knights_num + 1)
```

is already a list in `python2.7`. In `python3` it's not, but you didn't tag the version, but you use parenthetical `print`.

**Zero-indexing**

Python is zero-indexed. The first element of list `lst` is `lst[0]`, not `lst[1]`. When you pop the first element, you need to do `pop(0)` not `pop(1)`. Your `pop()` loop is all off by one for that reason - you're starting with the second knight instead of the first.

**Improved solution**

```
knight_table = list(range(get_num_knights()))
i = 0
while len(knight_table) > 1:
    knight_table.pop(i)
    i = (i+1) % len(knight_table)
print( "The knight who survived was no.", knights_temp_table[0]+1 )
```

**Avoiding `pop()`**

Now, for particularly long numbers of knights, it's possible that the `pop()` time could dominate your code runtime. `pop()` is linear-time after all - we have to shift the elements down one by one. So it's possible that the following could perform better:

```
num = get_num_knights()
knight_table = [True] * num
i = 0
while num > 1:
    knight_table[i % len(knight_table)] = False
    num -= 1

    living = 0
    while living < 2:
        i += 1
        living += knight_table[i % len(knight_table)]

print( "The knight who survived was no.", i % len(knight_table))
```

Comment: *"you're starting with the second knight instead of the first."* I think that's intentional if every **other** knight is to be popped off.

Comment: @Barry I disagree. `every other` suggests that the first is not an `other`

Answer (score 50):

Those poor knights.... what did they do to deserve that?

But, there is a mathematical treat that allows this problem to be solved in O(1) time, and space.

What does that mean? Well, it means that solving the problem for 1 knight takes just as long (and just as much memory) as solving it for 10, or 1000, or 1000000000000000 knights. How is this possible?

There's a pattern that emerges when you study this problem. If there is 1 knight, then knight 1 survives. If there's 2, then knight 1 survives, and, if we map this out for say the first 32 knights, we get:

> ```
> 1 -> 1
> 2 -> 1
> 3 -> 3
> 4 -> 1
> 5 -> 3
> 6 -> 5
> 7 -> 7
> 8 -> 1
> 9 -> 3
> 10 -> 5
> 11 -> 7
> 12 -> 9
> 13 -> 11
> 14 -> 13
> 15 -> 15
> 16 -> 1
> 17 -> 3
> 18 -> 5
> 19 -> 7
> 20 -> 9
> 21 -> 11
> 22 -> 13
> 23 -> 15
> 24 -> 17
> 25 -> 19
> 26 -> 21
> 27 -> 23
> 28 -> 25
> 29 -> 27
> 30 -> 29
> 31 -> 31
> 32 -> 1
> ```

Note that, at the powers-of-2, the surviving knight skips back to knight 1. Also, between the powers, the surviving knight increments by 2 (and is always odd).

The pattern is also easy to enumerate - find the largest power of 2 that's less than (or equal to) the count. Find how many knights there are after that power, double it, and add one.

It would look like this:

```
import math

def low_power(input):
    return 1 << int(math.floor(math.log(input, 2)))

def survivor(count):
    return 1 + 2 * (count - low_power(count))
```

So, calling `survivor(16)` will return 1. `survivor(60)` returns 57.

But, you can do crazy numbers now too, like `survivor(98765432123456789)` is 53415676171057707

See this code running on ideone: [Knights](http://ideone.com/aczAIJ)

Note that you have now confirmed you are using Python 3.4. Python 3.1 introduced the [`bit_length()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#additional-methods-on-integer-types) method. This makes the determination of the power much easier (from a programming perspective - bitlength can be thought of as an implementation of the log<sub>2</sub>):

```
def low_power(input):
    return 1 << (input.bit_length() - 1)
```

The same code running bit_length in python 3 is shown here [in ideone](http://ideone.com/j507rw) (also contains correct parenthesis for python 3 print statements).

Comment: @holroy - yeah, I suck at code reviews where the review is basically "do it this other way" - an algorithmic review, rather than a code review. The other answers cover much of the non-algorithmic aspects also (go on, and +1 them too).

Comment: No, no a very fine answer indeed. Being a math undergrad I also came to the same conclusion. But as mentioned I wanted to sharpen my rusty skills in programming, not mathematics ^^

Answer (score 19):

Remember, this is a round table. So if it's a round table... what better to use than a circular buffer?

```
from collections import deque

knights_table = deque(range(1, knights_num + 1))
```

Then you can emulate this much more simply:

```
while len(knights_table) != 1:
    knights_table.popleft()   # killed
    knights_table.rotate(-1)  # skipped

print("The knight who survived was no.", knights_table.pop())
```

One big advantage (other than simplicity) is, whereas `pop(i)` is `O(i) = O(n)` for `list`s, `popleft()` and `rotate(-1)` are `O(1)` for `deque`s.

`knights_num` should be extracted into a function, as others mentioned. However, this code is imperfect:

```
def get_num_knights():
    while True:
        num = input("Enter the number of knights: ")
        try:
            num = int(num)
            if num <= 0:  # if not a positive int print message and ask for input again
                print("Sorry, the number of knights must be a positive integer, try again")
            else:
                return num
        except ValueError:
            print("That's not an integer!")
```

Your `try` covers a lot more than wanted, which is dangerous. Restrict its coverage. Personally I'd also do `if not <wanted condition>` rather than `if <problematic condition>`, since whitelists are generally simpler and safer than blacklists. YMMV.

```
def get_num_knights():
    while True:
        num = input("Enter the number of knights: ")
        try:
            num = int(num)
        except ValueError:
            print("That's not an integer!")
            continue

        if not num > 0:  
            print("Sorry, the number of knights must be a positive integer, try again.")
            continue

        return num
```

Comment: Python elegance at its finest

Comment: Nice answer. One small nitpick for your input function. Here you assign a string to a variable called number. Which is only used as input of `int`. I would either give it its own name or directly move the input into the `try` block : `num = int(input(...`

Comment: @magu_ Moving the `input` into the `try` is bad practice because errors from the `input` call should be handled differently to errors from the `int` call. If you want to give it a different name when referring to a string, feel free, but I don't see the imperative to do so myself.

Answer (score 10):

I'll answer your questions then give more general advice.

1. The way you could use a generator for this would involve making a list anyway. Really, this is not a case where generator expressions are necessary anyway since the lists will be quite small and not take up a lot of space.
2. Possibly, but I think the clever solution is good and you should just explain it in comments. The `try except` way is messy and not *entirely* clear either, as you'd increment by 1 when it'd seem like you should go up in 2s to skip every other.
3. Linked lists are not commonly used in Python, so I would largely refer to answer 2 here too.

---

Now for general advice. You should avoid using temp variables when you don't need to. There's no real reason to separate `temp_num` and `knights_num` here. You may have previously needed to but your current code is airtight without it.

Also, it's good to have as few lines as possible in your `try` block. Sometimes to avoid errors, but also for good readability. You could use the `continue` keyword in your except clause and then move the other lines down below. Also I'd flip your `if`. If the number is valid, then you can `break`. Otherwise explain the number needs to be positive. This way your `print` doesn't need to be in an `else` block.

So here's how I'd rewrite this opening:

```
while True:
    knights_num = input("Enter the number of knights: ")
    try:
        knights_num = int(knights_num)
    except ValueError:
        print("That's not an integer!")
    if knights_num > 0:
        break
    print("Sorry, the number of knights must be a positive integer, try again")
```

You notice I also stripped the comment, your if condition was pretty clear without it. You might also want to prevent the user entering 1, which is theoretically valid but doesn't match the intent of the program.

Now, you have a lot of redundancy here:

```
knights_table = [i for i in range(1,knights_num+1)]
knights_temp_table = list(knights_table)
```

For a start, you could assign `range` to a list directly without the list comprehension. You also don't need to make a copy of `knights_table`, because you only ever use one of these variables later. So again, cut the temp variable.